# Cannot find aspx.cs file on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, webforms

I got an asp.net web forms project developed from someone. When I check the httpdocs folder on server, I cannot find the aspx.cs files for the corresponding .aspx files. When I check the CodeBehind attribute, it shows like "[FILENAME].aspx.cs". 
I also decompiled the dll of this project but even there the aspx.cs files were not present. 
Please tell me where can I find the event handling files of this project.

Comment: They are compiled into the dll. You will have to ask the original developer for the source code.

Comment: I checked the project dll file by decompling it and couldn't find the aspx.cs files.

Comment: If the website works it means the code from those .cs files are compiled into the dll.

Comment: @ChandmalTamboli search for the namespace and class not the filename. Aka Inherits="Namespace.Class" ( this is seen in your Page Directive) you can find by locating the namespace in the decompiler then search for the class within that namespace. And that is your code behind for the aspx page